# "Stream Fail & NoSuchElementException: null" with Cassandra 3.10

Tags: cassandra

I am having some problem with Cassandra 3.10 that when I try to join/decommission node, it cannot join/decommission the cluster with the "stream failed" exception, then it stops running. Util that time, node stays in JOINING state.

version : cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4

Node 1 Error log (seed)

```
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.0.120.11:44986] 2019-03-04 02:25:13,844 StreamResultFuture.java:116 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f ID#0] Creating new streaming plan for Bootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.0.120.11:44986] 2019-03-04 02:25:13,861 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Bootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.0.120.11:44988] 2019-03-04 02:25:13,861 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Bootstrap
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.0.120.11:44988] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,130 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 0 files(0.000KiB), sending 154 files(64.507MiB)
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.0.120.11:44988] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,401 StreamSession.java:706 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Remote peer 10.0.120.11 failed stream session.
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.0.120.11:44988] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,415 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Session with /10.0.120.11 is complete
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/10.0.120.11:44988EHgks ] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,417 StreamResultFuture.java:214 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Stream failed
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/10.0.120.11:44986] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,418 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.0.120.11
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:145) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter.lambda$write$0(CompressedStreamWriter.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.applyToChannel(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:350) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter.write(CompressedStreamWriter.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:101) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:52) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:41) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:408) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:380) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectlyInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(FileChannelImpl.java:493) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:141) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Node 2 Error log

```
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:12,424 StorageService.java:1435 - JOINING: Starting to bootstrap...
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:13,832 StreamResultFuture.java:90 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Executing streaming plan for Bootstrap
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] 2019-03-04 02:25:13,837 StreamSession.java:266 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Starting streaming to /10.0.110.11
INFO  [StreamConnectionEstablisher:1] 2019-03-04 02:25:13,842 StreamCoordinator.java:264 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f, ID#0] Beginning stream session with /10.0.110.11
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.0.110.11:5000] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,138 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 154 files(64.507MiB), sending 0 files(0.000KiB)
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,376 SecondaryIndexManager.java:365 - Submitting index build of pushcapabilityindx,presetsearchval for data in BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_sub_db/sub-94fe59103afb11e9a042932fa01bd6f1/mc-1-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/cassandra/data/abc_sub_db/sub-94fe59103afb11e9a042932fa01bd6f1/mc-2-big-Data.db')
ERROR [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,400 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.0.110.11
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.Throwables.maybeFail(Throwables.java:51) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:393) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:382) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildAllIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:269) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:215) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:386) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:64) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.lambda$indexPartition$20(SecondaryIndexManager.java:618) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.indexPartition(SecondaryIndexManager.java:618) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.internal.CollatedViewIndexBuilder.build(CollatedViewIndexBuilder.java:71) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$14.run(CompactionManager.java:1587) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_152]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.0.110.11:5000] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,407 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.0.110.11
java.lang.RuntimeException: Outgoing stream handler has been closed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:143) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.receive(StreamSession.java:655) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:523) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:317) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,409 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Session with /10.0.110.11 is complete
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,411 StreamResultFuture.java:214 - [Stream #bd205bb0-3e24-11e9-9d30-fb2ced1ba79f] Stream failed
ERROR [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,412 StorageService.java:1507 - Error while waiting on bootstrap to complete. Bootstrap will have to be restarted.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1502) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:962) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:681) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:612) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:394) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:215) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:481) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:571) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:249) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:1] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,412 StorageService.java:1497 - Error during bootstrap.
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:215) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:481) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:571) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:249) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
WARN  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,420 StorageService.java:1013 - Some data streaming failed. Use nodetool to check bootstrap state and resume. For more, see `nodetool help bootstrap`. IN_PROGRESS
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:14,420 CassandraDaemon.java:694 - Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:22,421 CassandraDaemon.java:725 - No gossip backlog; proceeding
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:22,482 NativeTransportService.java:70 - Netty using native Epoll event loop
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:22,531 Server.java:155 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork19.fe4816e, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.39.Final.38bdf86]
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:22,531 Server.java:156 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /10.0.120.11:7042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2019-03-04 02:25:22,564 CassandraDaemon.java:528 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
```

It succeeds in the following cases.

case 1.

drop index > node join/decommission SUCCEED > create index > node join/decommission FAIL

case 2.

table data backup (copy to command) > truncate table > data recovery (copy from command) > node join/decommission SUCCEED > New DATA insert from service > node join/decommission FAIL

case 3.

table data backup (copy to command) > drop table > create table >data recovery (copy from command) >node join/decommission SUCCEED > New DATA insert from service > node join/decommission FAIL

Unfortunately, I do not know about new insert queries from the service.

Q1. I want to see which queries come into Cassandra. Can I check queries from the service session?

Q2. Do you have any idea why stream fails in cassandra?

Comment: @SunJae did you solve this problem ? what was the cause of it ? and solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Enable trace on logging level from nodetool setlogginglevels  TRACE for cassandra transport. you can get queries on system.log.

Q2. Generally this error is coming due to network issue between nodes while streaming the data or gossip is not happening.